# Is there a JsAnd or JsOr when generate JS in lift?

Tags: javascript, scala, lift

I know this is very much a noob question...

I see lift provides utilities methods to generate javascript commands. I want to do the equivalent of:

```
JsIf((JsEq(ValById("disable-production"),JsTrue) || JsEq(ValById("disable-production"), JsTrue) , {
        Alert("Do something interesting...")
      })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [there is](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.http.js.JE%24%24JsOr):

```
import net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds._
import net.liftweb.http.js.JE._

val conditional = JsIf(
  JsOr(
    JsEq(ValById("disable-production"), JsTrue),
    JsEq(ValById("disable-something-else"), JsTrue)
  ),
  Alert("Do something interesting...")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better off writing this directly in string form and then evaluating it using `JsExp.strToJValue(<your expression>)`.

However, the direct answer to your question would be `JE.JsOr`.

```
JsIf((JE.JsOr(JsEq(ValById("disable-production"),JsTrue),
             JsEq(ValById("disable-production"), JsTrue)) , {
    Alert("Do something interesting...")
  })
```