# JavaScript source code generation library for scala

Tags: javascript, scala, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a library in scala that generates JavaScript from an abstract syntax tree.
I want to use it in an compiler that generates JavaScript at the end and I don't want to implement the pretty printing part myself.

Answer (score 7):

I spent half of yesterday researching this. It seems there is no *standard, standalone* solution. Every project I looked at rolled their own:

- **Scala-JS**: The JavaScript AST classes in Sébastien Doeraene's Scala-JS project are here: https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js/blob/master/compiler/src/main/scala/scala/tools/nsc/backend/js/JSTrees.scala and the conversion to strings is here: https://github.com/sjrd/scala-js/blob/master/compiler/src/main/scala/scala/tools/nsc/backend/js/JSPrinters.scala
- **JScala**: The JavaScript AST classes in Alexander Nemish's JScala project are here: https://github.com/nau/jscala/blob/master/jscala/src/main/scala/org/jscala/model.scala and the conversion to strings is here: https://github.com/nau/jscala/blob/master/jscala/src/main/scala/org/jscala/JavascriptPrinter.scala
- **s2js**: The JavaScript AST classes in Alvaro Carrasco's s2js project are here: https://github.com/alvaroc1/s2js/blob/master/plugin/src/main/scala/com/gravitydev/s2js/Trees.scala and the conversion to strings is here: https://github.com/alvaroc1/s2js/blob/master/plugin/src/main/scala/com/gravitydev/s2js/JsPrinter.scala
- **Lift** (see @thoredge's answer) combines AST classes with string generation in a single file, here: https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCommands.scala

How standalone and reusable might these various classes be? Just giving the code a visual onceover, it appears to me that the AST classes in JScala and s2js are standalone and could easily be borrowed by another project. The Scala-JS AST classes seem somewhat more entangled with their surroundings; Lift, even more so. (I welcome edits that improve on my informal impressions.)

How mature and battle-tested are these various projects? My informal impression is that they rank in descending order as follows: Lift, Scala-JS, JScala, s2js.

For my own project, I think I'm going to copy-and-paste the two source files from JScala and see how it goes.

P.S. I also mention, for completeness' sake:

- **js-scala** generates JavaScript strings directly from Scala ASTs, rather than going through intermediate JavaScript ASTs. (See for example https://github.com/js-scala/js-scala/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scala/js/gen/js/Compile.scala)  There is a very good blog post comparing js-scala and scala.js [here](http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2013/12/19/js-scala-and-scala-js/).
- I didn't look at **Scala-GWT**.

Comment: I took a deeper look at Lift, but as far as I remember the javascript ast isn't designed to express the full range of the language, so I could not use it.
I also looked at Rhino as a possibility, but it was quite cumbersome. Please consider that I looked at both over half a year ago and my not remember all details.
However in the end, I wrote my own: https://github.com/choeger/sl2/blob/master/src/main/scala/modules/JsSyntax.scala

Comment: I think JScala is the best choice here, but I'm biased :) It's just a single jar, published to Maven Central, so it's easy to add as a library. It's only 2 files you need if you want to copy-paste it in your code. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

The Lift web framework generates JavaScript from an AST. However, I've never looked at the generation end of it. The AST is described loosely here http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-10.html

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300263/is-there-a-jsand-or-jsor-when-generate-js-in-lift

Answer (score 2):

[StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) (from ANTLR) is pretty nice for code generation, I'd say, and it *does* track indentation and keeps indenting nested statements at the right level. Not really pretty printing, but better than nothing. (At the same time, I wonder why you want pretty printed JavaScript, if in the end it's going to be minified anyway.)

There is a Scala wrapper for StringTemplate (at least one, I seem to recall I saw more): http://software.clapper.org/scalasti/

Virtualized-scala doesn't seem to be what you need, I'd say, since that starts with Scala a Scala AST, and that's not what you seem to have.

However, if you're interested in those sort of things as well, you might want to check http://nescala.org/2013/talks#26 (by Alvaro Carrasco) as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Virtualized-Scala project, one of its instances is generating Javascript from Scala code, [js-scala](https://github.com/js-scala/js-scala). There you will find links for projects and talks about it.